# Canvas Arrary with touch event

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, android-canvas

Pleace tell me how to get the particular image or the particular  image id with the help of third party js or jquery
    I mean to say 
    in canvas  have an images in array form and want to add some alert event in a particular image..

```
For Eg..
function draw() {  
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),  
      img, i, image_array = [];  

  image_array.push("http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png");   
  image_array.push("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"); 

  image_array.push("http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg"); 

 image_array.push("http://chennaionline.com/images/gallery/2013/August/20130622091747/Raja-Rani-Latest-Movie-Stills-Photos-Images-20.jpg"); 
  // ...  

  for (i = 0; i < image_array.length; i++) {  
    img = new Image();  
    img.src = image_array[i];  
    img.onload = (function(img, i){ // temporary closure to store loop 
      return function () {          // variables reference 
        ctx.drawImage(img,i*img.width,i*img.height);  
      }  
    })(img, i);  
  }  
}
```

and now I want to add alert event on
    the particular image(logo.gif). so can you tell me
    how to get it and add the event on this particular image..**